# Rails file setup for a control panel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you setup your views, controllers and routes?

One controller for everything the control panel does, or many?

Firstly, let's try to think how we would view the various panels. Let's say our control panel is pretty simple. We have one panel to show all the users who have signed-up and can CRUD them, and another panel to show all of the images that have uploaded, and we can carry up CRUD on those too.

Routes:

```
scope path: 'control_panel' do
      get 'users', to: 'panels#users', as: :panel_show_users
      get 'photos', to: 'panels#photos', as: :panel_show_photos
end
```

Controller:

```
class PanelsController < ApplicationController
    def users
        @users = User.all
    end

    def photos
        @photos = Photo.all
    end
end
```

View file structure:

```
panels
  |_ users.html.erb
  |_ photos.html.erb
```

Okay, now I don't see any problems with that, to simply access the panels and populate the views with data. **Do you see any problems?**

Here is where I'm sort of at a cross roads though. What should I do when I want to Created Update and Delete a user/photo? Should I put them all in the PanelsController?

```
class PanelsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :protect

    def users
        @users = User.all
    end

    def update_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @user.update(user_params)
    end

    def photos
        @photos = Photo.all
    end

    def update_photo
        @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
        @photo.update(photo_params)
    end

    private

        def protect
            redirect_to root_url, error: 'You lack privileges!'
        end
end
```

While this would result in a large PanelsController, it would feel good to be able to execute that protect action and just one controller hook. It would also mean the routes would be easy to setup:

```
scope path: 'control_panel' do
      get 'users', to: 'panels#users', as: :panel_show_users
      post 'user', to: 'panels#update', as: :panel_create_user

      get 'photos', to: 'panels#photos', as: :panel_show_photos
      post 'photos', to: 'panels#photos', as: :panel_create_photo
end
```

**I should use resource routes here?**

Like I say, this will result in a huge panels controller, so I was thinking it may be better to have a separate controller for each resource and then redirect to `panels` views?

Routes:

```
scope path: 'control_panel' do
   resources :users
   resources :photos
end
```

Controllers:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
     def index
     end

     def show
     end

     def new
     end

     def create
     end

     def update
     end

     def destroy
     end       
end

class PhotosController < ApplicationController
     def index
     end

     def show
     end

     def new
     end

     def create
     end

     def update
     end

     def destroy
     end       
end
```

Still some quirks though. I have my Users#index action there, but what if I have two routes that return an index of all users? In the control panel, but also, when people are searching for another user, for example. Should I have two routes in the User controller? `def public_users` and `def control_panel_users`? That may be the answer. Could setup a hook to run `@users = User.all` in both of them, but redirect to a different location, and not have the `protect` method redirect them.

How should I protect these routes from non-admins? Should I move my protect method into the the application controller? Wouldn't this be a bit fiddly to setup?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController
    before_action :protect

    def protect end
end

class StaticController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action [:home, :about, :contact]

    def home
    end

    def about
    end

    def contact
    end
end
```

But that is my question. 1 control panel controller or no control panel controller.

I really wish there was more advanced tutorials out there :( Billions of books on CRUD, MVC and things, but nothing on advanced things like control panels and AJAX...

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a control panel controller. And to protect stuff from non-admins, use namespacing - read more about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

You can protect your 'admin'-namespaced controllers with authentication, and have the non-namespaced controllers open to the public (or open to non-admin users)

With regards to your `def public_users` and `def control_panel_users` question, you could just have two `def index` methods - one in the non-namespaced controller, and one in the admin-namespaced controller. They would each do different things.

So, you'd have 4 controllers in total:

2 non-namespaced, one for users, one for photos (containing all public stuff)
2 admin-namespaced, one for users, one for photos (containing all control panel stuff)

If you wanted, rather than using 'admin' as the namespace, you could use some other term you prefer - like 'panel'. 'Admin' is pretty conventional though.